# Not able to edit the Input Element after proving it a value using useState and alignment issue in div

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, frontend

I am working on a React project and facing two problems.

1. I have created an input field where I insert a value via a popover, but after that value is input, I am not able to add any more text to the input field.
   I have shown this with two images below
   [image]

From this popper, text is entered into the input field.

[image]

This is the input field, which I am not able to edit after the value is inserted.
So this is the first problem I am facing.

2. Now onto the second problem, which is that the alignment of the people list is not done in a proper manner. The Dropdown button "Full Access" is not in a straight line despite using `justify-content:space-between;`
   Again I am attaching an image for proper understanding.
   [image]

So, this is the second problem I am facing.
I am not attaching any code here as it was all in different files therefore I have upload the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/adityaxrawal/Notion-Share-Widget/main?file=%2FREADME.md&workspace=%257B%2522activeFileId%2522%253A%2522cla6zwlay000dl4iy1z4v6bri%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522sidekickItems%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522start%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522cla6zxgmk008d356jtfdxrod3%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D). It is upload on the codesandbox.io and I have also uploaded it on [Github](https://github.com/adityaxrawal/Notion-Share-Widget).
Please refer to the problem and help me out in this.
P.S: If you could assist me in adding search functionality to the input field that takes a value from popper, that would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As above @Dishonered suggest to me

```
   const AddPersontoSearchBar=(val)=>{
    setValue(Value + ',' + val.name)
    setAnchorEl(null)
  }
```

was a more general answer but for my code it needed a little modification and I did as mention below.

```
    if( Value === "") setValue(val.name + ',')
    else setValue(Value + ',' + val.name)
    setAnchorEl(null)
  }
```

For the second question, I neglected to properly examine my CSS and I overlooked the fact that a div was missing the '''min-width:300px;''' property, which was the root of the alignment issue. It was a rookie mistake on my part because I was new to React and Front end. Thank you to everyone who helped me with this; I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question I would try this

```
  const AddPersontoSearchBar=(val)=>{
    setValue(Value + ',' + val.name)
    setAnchorEl(null)
  }
```

Comment: I have tried it as you have suggested but it is working that way. Thank you so much for helping. If you could assist me in second one then it would be great.